# How can I extract original code from a `pre` tag?

Tags: html, .net, communication, c#-5.0, instant-messaging

I see every code token in a `pre` element is surrounded by a `span` with styling. How could I, e.g. extract the line:

```
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
```

from the HTML:

```
<pre lang="cs" id="pre82739" style="margin-top: 0px;"><span class="code-keyword">using</span> MySql.Data.MySqlClient;</pre>
```

The extracted code need not include syntax highlighting or other makeup, it must just compile to do the task it is intended to do.

The point of this is building a means to automatically transfer code from web pages, and eventually other devices and formats, to a destination where it can be quickly used, such as send it to Skype where the user can just copy and past it into their code.

Comment: Using what tools and technologies? What have you tried?

Comment: if you're trying to parse out the text from all the markup there are a bunch of libraries for each language, google should help you with that ;).

Comment: I am currently trying using regex and other ugly HTML removal code, but wanted to ask early before I am too far down the wrong road.

Comment: @dbarnes I'm currently trying to find a google term that doesn't bloody tell me how to parse HTML with C#, my default and first effort language.

Comment: How about jQuery's text() method?

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you want to **strip** the HTML and you're already trying (without success) regex, here's one I had to throw together for my own project you should be able to use.

```
/(<\/?(pre|span)[\s\S]*?>)|((style|class|id|lang|) ?\= ?['"][\s\S]*?['"])/gi
```

That's from a Javascript file so the wrapping may be different in C# but the actual expression should just about match.  Adjust as you see fit.

### [Live demo of course.](https://jsbin.com/ferefe/edit?html,js,console)

Answer (score 1):

The [HTML Agility Pack](https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack) makes this trivially easy. This library allows you to query and navigate HTML like you would a XML document using XPath or LINQ.

```
using System;
using HtmlAgilityPack;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string html = "<pre lang=\"cs\" id=\"pre82739\" style=\"margin-top: 0px;\"><span class=\"code-keyword\">using</span> MySql.Data.MySqlClient;</pre>";

            var document = new HtmlDocument();
            document.LoadHtml(html);

            //"//pre" is the XPATH to find all tags in the document that are named `<pre>`
            foreach (var node in document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//pre"))
            {
                //prints "using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;"
                Console.WriteLine(node.InnerText);
                Console.WriteLine("--------------------------");
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

If you passed in a full HTML document it would call `Console.WriteLine(node.InnerText);` once per `<pre>` block. For example here is it parsing your own question (you should get 5 results as of this writing, that number may change if other users use more `<pre>` blocks.)

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var document = new HtmlDocument();
    using (var client = new WebClient())
    {
        var page = client.DownloadString("http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31894197");
        document.LoadHtml(page);
    }
    foreach (var node in document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//pre"))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(node.InnerText);
        Console.WriteLine("--------------------------");
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```